# How do I report the reason a WCF ServiceHost is closing?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF service that in practice is hosted by IIS. I have implemented a custom ServiceHost (as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702697.aspx), and have overridden `OnClosing()` for the purpose of logging the closing event to our application log.

If possible, I would like to be able to log the *reason* the host is closing. We can do this is over in ASP.NET land (as described here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/14/433194.aspx).

Is something like this possible for a WCF service?